# rbenv bundle install tries to install gems into wrong path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get the following error message:

> Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.
>   You can cancel this installation and run:
>
> ```
>   bundle install --path vendor/bundle
> ```
>
> to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your
>   password   and install the bundled gems to Rubygems using sudo.

And here are some inspections that I've done:

```
me at me-ui-MacBook-Pro in ~
$ rbenv versions
  system
  2.1.6
  2.2.3
* 2.3.0 (set by /Users/me/.rbenv/version)
  2.3.0-dev

me at me-ui-MacBook-Pro in ~
$ rbenv version
2.3.0 (set by /Users/me/.rbenv/version)

me at me-ui-MacBook-Pro in ~
$ gem environment home
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
```

**Q: why does it trying to install to system Rubygems?**

Comment: Is `/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0` writable?

Comment: Which ruby is bundler installed in (ie what does `which bundler ` return?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just had the same problem and this solved it for me:

```
gem uninstall bundler
gem update --system
rbenv rehash
gem install bundler
```

Most likely only `gem update --system` were mandatory.